# Use of Route Name in Routes in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-5

The `default Asp.Net MVC` route is :

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Default", // Route name
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);
```

And, If we want to make custom routes then we can do that also, like given below :

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Privacy", // Route name
  "privacy",
   new { controller = "Home", action = "Privacy" }
);
```

So, my question is that what is the purpose of **'Route name'** in routes given above or can we have more then one Routes with same **'Route name'**.

Comment: To answer one of the questions here: "route names must be unique."

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is a shorthand way to reference to the route, by using

```
@Html.RouteLink("Privacy");
```

Here an article on ASP.NET about routing, which helped me a lot...

[ASP.NET MVC Routing Overview (C#)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)

Comment: Sadly, the article does not mention `Html.RouteLink`.

Comment: How you call Routelink without linkText paramete? this is MSDN source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.routelink(v=vs.118).aspx